# Laravel use php 7 in the terminal on Bluehost

Tags: .htaccess, php-7, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.5

I have added this to my .htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
```

This gets me php 7 for that domain. phpinfo() says 7.0.12.  Customer Service at Bluehost do not seem to understand that when I use composer to install Laravel 5.5 it bails because the system is using php 5.6.31. Laravel 5.5 needs PHP 7.

```
php -v //returns 5.6.31 in the directory where my phpinfo file is.
```

Solved using composer by using

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Now when running artisan commands it just returns. no error or anything. What am I missing to be able to use `php artisan -v` for example?

Added error reporting and get this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 235
```

which I believe impies I am using the older version of php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the path to php 7 on my bluehost shared hosting box.

Add this to .bash_profile in your home directory:

```
alias php='/opt/php70/bin/php';
```

Save and then:

```
source .bash_profile
php -v
```

returns

```
PHP 7.0.12 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2016 17:39:09) ( NTS )
```

Now you can use php artisan etc.

Comment: just what i needed ... amazing answer . thanks alot